# Image processing to identify number of dark lines in image

Tags: image, octave, matlab

I'm currently working on a project to automate the reading of a type of sensor (very similar to a pregnancy test stick, see figure below). The stick is dipped in a sample and either 1 or 2 lines appear.

[image]

The sensor is then photographed and it is this image that needs to be processed. My question is: what is the best way of going about this? From what I've read about the subject the MatLab image processing toolbox is very good, but that's a little beyond my budget. Are there any free/ cheapish alternatives that would be suitable?

Comment: I haven't used it before but the [Octave image package](http://octave.sourceforge.net/image/) looks pretty good and there is a fair chance that you'll be able to use it nativly in Matlab

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A line detector is not that difficult to write code by yourself. Search for canny edge detector and hough transform for more details. And there are also some codes written by others that are shared in mathwork exchange pages, such as :
http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/34637-line-detection-using-hough-transform/content/try3.m
http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/35754-wide-line-detector
If you have the jpeg or other images rather than the raw data, imageJ is also a good choice for various image processing approaches: http://rsb.info.nih.gov/ij/download.html (though imageJ can also import binary data format file)

Answer (score 2):

The ImageJ toolbox might suit you. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ImageJ

Answer (score 2):

This would be possible using [OpenCV](http://opencv.org/) using Java, Python or C/C++.

> OpenCV (Open Source Computer Vision Library) is an open source
>   computer vision and machine learning software library. OpenCV was
>   built to provide a common infrastructure for computer vision
>   applications and to accelerate the use of machine perception in the
>   commercial products. Being a BSD-licensed product, OpenCV makes it
>   easy for businesses to utilize and modify the code.